# How to erase an element from a vector using a std::move_iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, erase, stdmove

This is a Josephus Permutation problem, it was solved by using `std::move()`, but now I have to switch to using `std::move_iterator` (by using `std::make_move_iterator()`)
However, this doesn't compile:

```
template <typename RandomIt>
void MakeJosephusPermutation(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, uint32_t step_size) {
    list<typename RandomIt::value_type> pool;
    for (auto it = make_move_iterator(first); it != make_move_iterator(last); ++it) {
        pool.push_back(*it);
    }
    auto cur_pos = make_move_iterator(pool.begin());
    while (!pool.empty()) {
        *(first++) = *cur_pos;
        if (pool.size() == 1) {
            break;
        }
        const auto next_pos = LoopIterator(pool, next(cur_pos));

        pool.erase(cur_pos); //-> *"No matching member function for call to 'erase'"

        cur_pos = next_pos;
        for (uint32_t step_index = 1; step_index < step_size; ++step_index) {
            cur_pos = LoopIterator(pool, next(cur_pos));
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find info on this on cppreference, how can you remove the element from the vector in this case? I.e. I know that the element will have been moved, but not having some sort of "erase" there messes up the algorithm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::list<T>::erase()` takes an argument of type `std::list<T>::const_iterator` or `std::list<T>::iterator`.  See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase

You are trying to call erase with parameter of type `std::move_iterator<Iter>`, but there is no support for converting it into one of the list iterator types: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator

You should access the base iterator to call erase:

```cpp
pool.erase(cur_pos.base());
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I did understand why it wasn't compiling (the mismatch of the iterator types), but I totally overlooked the fact that it is so simple to get the "normal" iterator from a move iterator >_< ! This helps a lot! For some reason it was not mentioned in the theory of the lesson on move_iterators, and the method "base()" on cppreference didn't really catch my eye as the solution to the problem here (as I wasn't familiar with the concept of a "base" iterator, thank you for the tip!)

Comment: Btw, initially as a sort of a work-around I tried using pool.remove(*cur_pos), but that did not pass the performance tests (took too long).